# Fiber bundle and local trivial fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration, compact-manifolds

If we have a fiber bundle $\pi:M\longrightarrow N$  which M and N be two compact smooth manifolds,is there a fibration on $M$?

If we have a surjective submersion $\pi:M\longrightarrow N$ such that for every $y\in N$ the fibers $\pi^{-1}(y)\subset M$ diffeomorphic on neighborhood of $M$, is there a fibration on $M$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Phrasing questions well is tough, but it really improves your chances of getting a good and useful answer. You've written: " locally fiber bundle between". I think that there must be some words missing here. Please re-read your question to be sure it makes sense. Right now, it doesn't.

Comment: @JohnHughes sorry, thank you for your points!

Comment: @JohnHughes I edit it.

Comment: A fibre bundle is always a fibration. How do you define locally trivial fibration ? this seems to imply a fibre bundle by the very definition

Comment: @Max I mean a local trivial fibration is a surjective submersion that locally fibers  are diffeomorphic.

Comment: @Max Are you have other definition?

Comment: Usually, a locally trivial fibration or things of this type are maps that locally look like the projection $U\times F\to U$ for some $F$. This implies the definition you just gave, but a priori is stronger

Comment: @Max I confused between definition,Can you edit my question with standard definition?

Comment: But I don't know what definitions you want; and the problem with the standard definitions is that the problem will end up being "oh, it's the definition" + maybe there's a difference in definition between the continuous setting and the smooth setting other than "all functions are smooth"

Comment: @Max I edit it, why fibration is a categorical notion?

Comment: The definition of fibration is more categorical than the definition of fiber bundle because it just ask that certain maps exist to make a diagram commute. A fiber bundle asks for maps pertaining to certain open sets in your space to exist. Open sets don’t generally make sense in an arbitrary category.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Can you definition of fibration in category of smooth manifold?

Comment: The definition will be the same but the maps will be smooth.

Comment: @ConnorMalin so what different between fiber bundle and smooth fibration?